# Where do I go to change the Battlelog email so it is linked to the PS3/Origin account?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3, battlelog

I have signed up for an EA Origin account but can't get into the BF3 Battle Log on the PS3.  I noticed that the Battle log shows another email linked to it and I can't figure out how to change it.  I go to http://battlelog.battlefield.com/ and use my Origin account to sign in but it won't even let me log in.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. What i did was go onto a computer, log into the account and change the email. This can not be done from the ps3, it has to be done from a computer.

Comment: you can also contact EA/Origin and they can link it for you if there is a problem and you cannot do it. I had to do that, but if you do, make sure you get the password from them too because I didn't think about it and they did not give it to me.